# How to Get HTTP status code with curl post

Tags: curl

I'm using curl for GET at the command line on Linux in order to get http response code. The response bodies are printed to standard out, which is fine, but I can't see any solution how to get curl for POST to print the HTTP status code(200, 404, 403 etc). Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get only the `http_code` you could try:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null --head -w "%{http_code}" -X POST "https://httpbin.org/post"
```

you can read/remember it like:

- `-s` Silent mode
- `-o` Write output to /dev/null
- `--head` Get headers
  only
- `-w "%{http_code}"` write out the HTTP Status code

To get all the headers from your request try:

```
curl -I -X POST "https://httpbin.org/post"
```

It will return something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 20:12:01 GMT
Server: nginx
Content-Length: 294
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: How to use this command on a windows command prompt i tried the command `curl -I -s -w %{http_code} server:8080/page/` and it throws `curl: no URL specified!`

Comment: I am guessing that you'll need to speficy the protocol in the destination URL like so:
curl -I -s -w %{http_code} https://server:8080/page/

Answer (score 1):

```
 curl -X POST --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null --data  "{your_json_input}}" -H 'Content-Type:application/json' http://your_url
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of `curl` have `--fail-with-body` that has the same return value as `--fail` but still prints the response body.